# MS access - How to make sure 2 forum lines offset eachother

Tags: ms-access

I have an access table with the following columns

```
  Field Name            Data Type
 Sending_Division_$    - Currency
 Receiving_Division_$  - Currency
 Check_Total_$         - Currency
```

I need to have Check_Total_$ = 0 if the other 2 columns cancel each other out (one is negative and one is positive). I keep getting the

> "Invalid SQL Syntax - cannot use multiple columns in a column-level
>   CHECK constraint.

I have searched the web and tried to use the validation Rule box with no avail.

```
=[Sending_Division_$]+[Receiving_Division_$]
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for **Access 2010+**.
You will have to redesign the table (better from the start). 
First of all the table needs a "Primary Key", say `Id` as `AutoNumber`. 
Then add the first 2 columns so now you have 3 columns (with the ID).
Save the design of the table (without exiting) and now add the column `Check_Total_$` and select `Calculated` under *"Data Type"*.
In the *"Expression Builder"* build the expression you want as:

```
[Sending_Division_$]+[Receiving_Division_$]
```

Save the table.

Comment: worked perfect. As I think about it, is there a way to assure the two columns added together = 0 without a new column? Something like the form kicking back? Thanks

Comment: The above method does not assure that the 2 columns will add up together to 0, right? All it does is to show the difference of the 2 columns. You know the error that Access raises:*Invalid SQL Syntax - cannot use multiple columns in a column-level CHECK constraint.* when you try to set a check constraint. I don't know of any way of creating such a constraint, but as I think about it, it is hard to grasp because it would make a circular reference because it should be applied to both columns. I guess this has to be done by VBA code.

Comment: Thanks forpas. I appreciate you help. I like the idea of VBA Code. I will create coding in the submit button saying those two columns have to equal each other.